# Alamofire 5 inherit 'DataRequest'

Tags: swift, alamofire

Trying to inherit `DataRequest` from Alamofire gives me an access error because from Alamofire 5 I see that `DataRequest` class is public and not open. My question is: Is there a possibility to inherit it without modifying the Alamofire sources?

Edit 1:

I'm looking to make a CoreData cache system. I'll like to save the request and the response before decoding it. In routes I specify the age and size of each one.

```
@discardableResult
    func performRequest<T: Decodable>(for route: Route, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), completion: @escaping (Result<T, AFError>) -> Void) -> DataRequest {
        return sessionManager.request(NetworkRouter(route))
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .cacheResponse()
            .responseDecodable(decoder: decoder) { (response: DataResponse<T, AFError>) in
                completion(response.result)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `DataRequest` is purposefully not `open`. If you'd like to discuss alternatives to subclassing, update your question with your requirements or feel free to open a topic on our [Swift forum](https://forums.swift.org/c/related-projects/alamofire/).

---

To separate out a cache, it really depends on what you're caching. If you're caching data and want to operate directly in the request pipeline, you can implement `CachedResponseHandler` to decided when and where to cache responses. If you want to do it after a response, you could put the handling in your `responseDecodable`, or implement your own `ResponseSerializer` if you need access to the raw `Data`.

Ultimately, where you'd implement the cache comes down to what exactly you're caching and when you want to cache it. A subclass isn't necessary.

Comment: @DeryckLucian Updated answer.